# Proving that a following curve is a $C^\infty$ manifold but not a $C^1$ manifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

> The curve C\subset $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined by the equation $y^2=x^3$. Give a $C^\infty$-atlas on $C$ that is not a sub atlas of the $C^1$ atlas induced from $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I think I do not understand the concept of atlases and I'd really appreciate if someone can show explicitly what is the atlas that is induced from $\mathbb{R}^2 $ and whats basically the difference (how can I find a $C^\infty$ one? does the meaning is that $C$ can be embedded smoothly in higher dimension of $\mathbb{R}$ but not in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: “… but not a …” is the wrong reading of this exercise. A $C^{\infty}$ atlas is a $C^1$ atlas. It is definitely not saying that the curve is not a $C^1$-manifold.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, if an atlas is $C^\infty$, then it is also $C^1$, by definition.  A $C^\infty$ atlas demands that all derivatives be continuous, and a $C^1$ demands only that the first derivative is continuous.

This is a one-dimensional manifold.  Let's call your curve $M$.  So, an atlas is going to be some functions $f_i: \mathbb{R} \to M$ such that the images of these functions cover the curve.  These functions have to be bijections, and have to have the appropriate number of derivatives.

As an example, the curve is
$$
M := \{(x, y) | y^2 = x^3\}.
$$

The atlas consists of the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to M$ defined by:
$$
f(t) := (\sqrt[3]{t^2}, t).
$$
The image of this function is exactly $M$.  It is a bijection.  Now you just have to ask what happens when you start taking derivatives.  With this example, something goes wrong at the second derivative.

The problem is asking you to find functions, $f_i: \mathbb{R} \to M$ that are bijections, cover $M$, and have all their derivatives.  Note, that my example used one function to cover the whole curve, but you can use any number of them that you want.

It is important to note that $M$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in this example, so the derivative property is a little simplified.  Between abstract manifolds you need to first ask what you are taking a derivative of.

EDIT: I've been asked to specify the general derivative property.  Each map $f_i: \mathbb{R} \to M$ has an inverse $f^{-1}_i: M \to \mathbb{R}$.  The condition you need to check is that $f^{-1}_k \circ f_i$ is $C^\infty$, whenever the image of $f_k$ and $f_i$ intersect.  Since my example only has one function, then it's just $f^{-1}\circ f = \operatorname{Id}$, where $\operatorname{Id}$ is the identity, which is certainly $C^\infty$.  If the dimension of your manifold is $n$, then replace $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$.

As a simple example, we could get an atlas on the graph of $y = x^2$, with two functions $\mathbb{R} \to M$ by $f_1(t) := (1 - e^t, (1 - e^t)^2)$ and $f_2(t) := (e^t - 1, (e^t - 1)^2)$.  The images of these overlap on $-1 < x < 1$.  The inverse for $f_1$ is $f^{-1}_1(x, x^2) := \log(1 - x)$.  Then we get the transition on $-1 < x < 1$:
$$
(f^{-1}_1 \circ f_2)(t) = \log(2 - e^t).
$$
And, $t \mapsto \log(2 - e^t)$ is $C^\infty$.

Comment: I was going to ask about the derivative property, as I understand, a $C^r$ atlas means that the **transition maps** are $C^r$ and here your demand is that the chart itself ($f$) would be differentialbe. Also if there is only one chart in your atlas, dosent it mean that the atlas is $C^\infty$ ? (because there is only one transition map and its the identity) I'd aprreciate if you can elaborate on the derivative property

Comment: @FreeZe I edited in an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem rather points in the direction that you can indeed install the tangent space (I use the notation from above) $T_{(0,0)}M$ by pulling it back via the bijection
$$
f:\mathbb{R}\to M,~t\mapsto\big(t^{2/3},t\big)
$$
in order to make $M$ a $\mathcal{C}^\infty$-manifold. In other words, you define a function $\phi:M\to\mathbb{R}$ to be smooth if $\phi\circ f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth in the usual sense. Then you obtain tangent spaces, tangent vectors and vector fields, as usual, as (space of (point)) derivations. While everywhere in $M\backslash\{(0,0)\}$ the tangent space on $M$ may be identified with a subspace of the tangent space on $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the respective points, this is not true for $T_{(0,0)}M$, the latter is just an abstract space and can not be identified with a subspace of $T_{(0,0)}\mathbb{R}^2$ in order to make $M$ a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

However, that's just my opinion based on the explicit exclusion of the "sub-atlas [...] from $\mathbb{R}^2$" as stated in the problem. Also, I'm not entirely sure how you (@J126) want to find an analog of $f$ which "has all its derivatives" in the problem point. On the other hand, what I have described above (and what to me the problem sounds asking for) is a standard example to show students that not all manifolds are submanifolds, even if they are defined as subsets of smooth manifolds.